# ReferenceError: browser is not defined at chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am doing some JavaScript coding practice on VS Code. When I add some new JS features in the code, the live-server page cannot respond and an error msg pops up:ReferenceError: browser is not defined . If I reopen live-server, the problem will be fixed while I need to reopen live-server whenever I added new features. The browser is Chrome. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRQMQ.png)

I tried to reload the page when I included new JS features in JS file. If not, the error message pops up. The live-server function was ok when I was doing HTML/CSS coding exercise.

Comment: The library needs to run in a real browser, I suspect VSCode is using node.js to run scripts locally.

Comment: yes, I chose node.js to run scripts locally and also used the default go-live function of VScode. How can I fix the error? Should I terminate node.js? How? thanks!

Comment: reading and writing minified JS code is the way to go. What is `self.browser`?

Comment: why do you need to put parenthesis around an arrow function

Comment: `self.chrome = self.chrome;` what is the purpose of this

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: @ rioV8 I do not know where these code come from as they were not a part of my JS code. Could you please explain what this means? 'reading and writing minified JS code '